# Written equivalent to "soundbite"

Tags: single-word-requests

Wikitionary describes soundbite as:

> a short extract from a recorded interview or speech, chosen for its succinctness or concision.

What would be an equivalent word for a written medium, as opposed to audio?

I've used several phrases over the years to describe these but nothing as succinct as soundbite.

Example usage:

> That blog was full of wordbites that expressed the thoughts I had.

What this would mean is roughly one of the following 3 or a mix of them:

- That blog was full of phrases which put very clearly the nuanced thoughts I've had on the subject but haven't been able to express very well.
- That blog was full of phrases which read really well and communicate the ideas very clearly, which I also had.
- That blog was full of quotable phrases which I'd rather use instead of explaining my thoughts in my own words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Snippet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snippet) works well in this case:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : a small part, piece, or thing
> *especially* : a brief quotable passage
>
> // *snippets* from the author's newest novel
> // read them a *snippet* of his latest poem

In the example sentence in the question:

> That blog was full of *snippets* that expressed the thoughts I had.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll actually have to revise the example sentence. The example sentence is needlessly verbose because I wanted to show the meaning of what the intended word would say. Unfortunately, I made the mistake of repeating the meaning as a part of the sentence.

Comment: Please see the edits. Perhaps snippet is still a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Not as idiomatic, but *apothegm* has the intended meaning:

> **apothegm**: a short clever saying that is intended to express a general truth [[Cambridge English
>   Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/apothegm)

.........

> **apothegm**: a short, witty, instructive saying [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apothegm)]

.........

- *I am reminded of the absolutely necessary apothegm written somewhere by Camus: 'Classicism is nothing but [R]omanticism with the excess removed.'* [[Suicides and Jazzers, Hayden Carruth](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VL5W2P1c1iUC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22apothegm+written%22&source=bl&ots=IhGFDq0XTu&sig=ACfU3U0_Vvh2n8aFQn8DY8SK3NPPuPWwAA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22apothegm%20written%22&f=false)]

The example sentence illustrates that apothegms may be non-verbal, and (at least at the time of penning) not widely used enough to be considered fixed expressions.

(It is quite possible that 'soundbite' itself is considered to have broadened enough in meaning to include written examples that will or could well be be read aloud.)